Portuguese residence: if I enter Schengen through Paris or Amsterdam, will they admit me as a tourist, instead of a resident in Portugal?
I hold Portuguese residence and I can travel to Schengen with my passport without visa.  The validity of my residence permit has been extended until June 2025, but the Portuguese authorities are currently unable to provide me with an actual renewed residence permit See https://aima.gov.pt/pt/documentos-e-vistos-validos-e-aceites-ate-30-de-junho-de-2025-valid-and-accepted-documents-and-visas-until-30-june-2025
Now my question. I enter Schengen through Paris or Amsterdam. Will they admit me as a tourist, instead of a resident in Portugal, which is what I am? I hope that I will not be subject to the 90/180 days rule.
Any suggestions ?

The Schengen area does not have any concept of being admitted in a particular status.  Your status depends on the visa or residence document you hold, if any, and, if you're limited to short stays, on how much time you've spent in the Schengen area recently.  (This is in contrast to many other places such as the US and the UK; for example, if a Schengen border officer admits you incorrectly when you are already over the 90 day limit, you are overstaying from the moment you enter despite the officer having admitted you.)


Will they admit me as a tourist, instead of a resident in Portugal, which is what I am? I hope that I will not be subject to the 90/180 days rule.

There isn't a difference, really. You do not get admitted as this or that, this is not something border guards in the Schengen area can do, nowhere it could get recorded, and no consequences of any kind. It's also perfectly possible to enter for a short stay and switch to another status, the only thing that will determine the maximum length of your stay is your status in Portugal, not the border guards' interpretation.
Instead, the main thing to worry about is how you can account for your past stays. If you have already been in the Schengen more than 90 days during the last 180-day period, it is essential to be able to document your status in Portugal, otherwise border guards would have to refuse entry. This (granting or refusing entry) is the only decision they can take.

A stay as a resident is excluded from the 90/180 day rule, so it's not something to worry about.

@André the point is that if OP cannot prove he was a resident (at least at the time he was in Portugal), then that time would be counted, that’s why being able to prove it may be important. OTOH, many countries do not stamp passports of residents, so they may have a hard time alleging OP was in Schengen at all. Of course the worst case is if they have an entry stamp, no exit stamp, and no way to prove residency…

@André That is exactly what my answer states. Instead, what you need to worry about is showing that you are a resident.

There is a practical difference: If they deem you to be a tourist, they'll ask tourist questions and ask for tourist documents (return flight, accomodation).

@ave Yes that's true, that's related to my point on documenting your status to account for past stays but all that is only relevant before the decision to grant entry. After that, you haven't been admitted “as a tourist”, there really isn't any difference. Which is why I think the OP should really worry about being granted entry in the first place.
